# Why doesn't the Nikon D90 record ISO in EXIF?

Tags: metadata, iso, nikon-d90, exiftool

Why is there no ISO data in EXIF of images taken with Nikon D90? I'm using [exiftool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It appears that the Nikon D90 [does record ISO information](http://www.flickr.com/photos/zzapback/5911996935/meta/) in the files - I'd suggest the fault is with exiftool.

Comment: You right! Something wrong with my exiftool. Thanks a lot. I've upgraded it and works good :) Thanks for a tip.